# Tsql query Case statment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, union

I'm trying to write a query (Microsoft SQL SERVER) the looks like :

```
select  productid from T1 
union 
select  productid from T2 
union 
select ProductID from T3
```

The issue is that I want that one of that union will be depend of a value(lets say @x)
So, I write this query :

```
select case when @x=1 then  productid end 
from T1 
union 
select  productid from T2 
union 
select ProductID from T3
```

But its still scan all T1.

I know that "Case" scan the table even if its not match the condition:
select  case when 1=2 then  productid end from T1 
How can I write a query that base on a value will now if execute or not ??
Something like  : case @x=1 then select productid  from T1 end....
* I need to find a way without dynamic sql 
Thanks

Comment: use a WHERE clause in the first union term like: `select productid from t1 where @x=1 union ...`

Comment: I can't , because @x is independent, Its not part of t1 . I also tried :select  productid from t1 where exists (@x=1), But still it scan all t1 even when @x!=1.

Comment: Then explain what you are actually trying to do, because I have used this technique successfully, and efficiently, for nearly three decades now.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

Set @SQL = N' select  productid From T1 '
Set @SQl = @SQL + N' UNION select  productid From T2'
if(@x=1)
Set @SQl = @SQL + N' UNION select  productid From T3'

exec (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help,
I manage to do it as Pieter  suggest, with a where clause . The query look like

```
select productid from t1 union select productid from t2
union select productid from t3 inner join t4 on t3.id=t4.t3id where t3.value=@x
```

Although I didn't want to use t4 table (because @x is one per all t3) 
Thank you all.